# Using Cocoapods Beta with Travis

Tags: ios, cocoapods, travis-ci

When trying to install a Podfile (With cocoapods 1.0.0 Beta 6) with multiple Targets, Travis fails with error messages like:

([!] Unable to satisfy the following requirements:
- `p2.OAuth2` required by `Podfile`
- `p2.OAuth2` required by `Podfile`
- `p2.OAuth2` required by `Podfile`
- `p2.OAuth2 (= 2.2.5)` required by `Podfile.lock`
None of the spec sources contain a spec satisfying the `p2.OAuth2` dependency.

Has anyone had this before?

Answer (score 5):

So, after talking to the support, their suggestion to call "pod setup" when using a custom pod version fixed the issue of cocoapods not finding the specs.